# Deregistering a font with NSIS

Tags: nsis

When I try to uninstall a font like that...

```
Section "un.Uninstall"
    StrCpy $FONT_DIR $FONTS
    !insertmacro RemoveTTFFont "$FONTS\Vani.ttf"
    !insertmacro RemoveTTFFont "$FONTS\Vanib.ttf"
    SendMessage ${HWND_BROADCAST} ${WM_FONTCHANGE} 0 0 /TIMEOUT=5000
SectionEnd
```

I get the following error message:

```
Error in macro GetFileNameCall on macroline 2
Error in macro RemoveTTFFont on macroline 9
(...) aborting process
```

In other words, there's something wrong with the following section in the `FontReg.nsh` file:

```
!ifmacrondef GetFileNameCall
   !macro GetFileNameCall _PATHSTRING _RESULT
        Push `${_PATHSTRING}`
        Call GetFileName
        Pop ${_RESULT}
   !macroend
!endif

!ifndef GetFileName
   !define GetFileName `!insertmacro GetFileNameCall`    
    Function GetFileName
        Exch $0
        Push $1
        Push $2    
        StrCpy $2 $0 1 -1
        StrCmp $2 '\' 0 +3
        StrCpy $0 $0 -1
        goto -3    
        StrCpy $1 0
        IntOp $1 $1 - 1
        StrCpy $2 $0 1 $1
        StrCmp $2 '' end
        StrCmp $2 '\' 0 -3
        IntOp $1 $1 + 1
        StrCpy $0 $0 '' $1    
        end:
        Pop $2
        Pop $1
        Exch $0
    FunctionEnd
!endif
```

Can someone, if not tell me how to fix the bug, at least point me in the right direction? 
It would be useful for the community as many have had this problem but no one has solved it yet, like here - http://forums.winamp.com/showthread.php?t=245701

Comment: Are you using [this](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Register_Fonts) or [that](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Advanced_Font_Installation) to install/remove fonts? It seems the latter is a more recent macro with one issue („Attempted to fix uninstall compiler error”) fixed this year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't received any answers unfortunately, but I must share the solution I came up with, since I saw that lots of people have had the same problem.

There is a bug in macros to remove fonts, namely "RemoveTTF", "RemoveTTFFont" and similiar sounding ones in the following files : FontReg.nsh, FontRegAdv.nsh. All of them use the same function called "GetFileNameCall" which causes the error. The problem with this function is that **it sees "FontName" and "FontFileName" as the same item**! As a matter of fact, font file name differs from font name. I solved the problem by copying the needed code from FontRegAdv.nsh and replacing FontFileName and FontName variables with the actual font file names and font names.

Comment: You did not receive any answers because you never told us which of the two font headers from the wiki you are using. I already fixed one of the wiki pages last year?